# Is there other method for sending data offline that is cross-platform instead of Bluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, offline

I'm developing an application that will require sending data offline to other users of the app.
The are two different users: Managers and Salesmen. Salesman users will login with a PIN that Managers will generate. As the Manager need to do a first login he will be required to access the internet at least once. 
The problem become more complicated when I need to send product lists and other informations about the event created by the Manager when both Manager and Salesman are offline.

This is due to the possible scenario where users won't have internet connection ( even 4G or 3G).
QR Code won't handle the case because the data can be more complex than a big String.

The data will have:

- List of validated Employees (users with a name and a PIN number)
- List of All Categories
- List of all Products available (Product Name, Product Price, ProductID, Product Category)

Is there possible alternatives instead of Bluetooth? The idea must be cross-platform (ios x android) as this are our targets. Couldn't found much about offline methods. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using WIFI will give you the ability to use the same code for online AND offline, while its offline you can make the manager application part of the server code.

Comment: Thank you Josh, as I replied on other comments, I haven't thought of something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use wifi instead. 
Then you can use same code for both offline and online.

If it is offline
Make manager App part as server code (like TCP/UDP server) and make the sales person part as the client. 
If it is online 
make both Manager and sales person connect to a central server then exchange data from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use wifi instead. 
Then you can use same code for both offline and online.

If it is offline
Make manager App part as server code (like TCP/UDP server) and make the sales person part as the client. 
If it is online 
make both Manager and sales person connect to a central server then exchange data from there.
Here is a realy simple example with TCP
https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry I couldn't figure out how it would work. Both of them don't have wifi or any internet conection. 
How a server-client idea will help? I got it that when the Manager sign in the salesman would only be able to do get the data by connecting to a Manager, but wouldn't this require internet connection?
I got a little bit confused.

Comment: No. This will not require internet connection. Make the manager app to create wifi hotspot.
Salesman as wifi device.

Comment: So this will work as long as they are close to each other within the same network

Comment: Thank you, I understood now. this TCP server can run on the background of a thread?

Comment: Yes. You should make two threads for recieving and transmitting.